# mysql synchonizing inserts and updates with transactions

Tags: mysql, locking

I have two tables, call them transaction and master. The master has a primary key which is also a foreign key in the transaction table. If a transaction comes in with a key that's not in the master table, I add it to the master, if it's already in the master I update some fields in the master. How do I synchronize this so it works if two transactions arrive at the same time, both with the same key that isn't in the master yet?

I can see how to do it with LOCK TABLES, but is there some way to do it with BEGIN/COMMIT? If two transactions both try to add a record with the same unique key, what happens?

Yes, I am using InnoDB and I looked at the various consistency level but the descriptions are heavy on updating existing records and light on inserting new ones.

Update: to answer my own question,

INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE blah

This is a relatively recent addition to MySQL.  Guess I wasn't the only person with this problem.

Comment: Sync not needed. Unconditional INSERT IGNORE will solve.

Comment: @Akina that won't solve he updates (possibly running totals or something)

Comment: Do you use InnoDB tables (you should) - you should read about ACID and transactions (database, not money :) ). The DB is made with these things in mind.

Comment: @jkavalik ?? Why? The problem is master table's row insertion. IGNORE removes all problems - one of concurrent threads inserts and all another ignores, but after insertion attempt the row in master is present anycase.

Comment: Don't use `LOCK TABLES`.  Do provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the SQL statements that approximate what you need to do.  We'll help you with  things like `FOR UPDATE` to get it finished.

Comment: @Akina _" if it's already in the master I update some fields in the master"_ - that update may depend on the previous values in that row. INSERT IGNORE means no update takes place, REPLACE would mean old values are forgotten.

Comment: @jkavalik If update needed then not INSERT IGNORE but INSERT ODKU.

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. You might want to flesh out the bit where you write that ***...that's not in the master table, I add it to the master, if it's already in the master I update some fields in the master***. How do you achieve this? The information is relevant for a possible solution. If you have already implemented a solution then we require that information to determine how a solution could look like. Add more details to your question via the [edit] link. Thanks.

Comment: @Akina, yes, that could work, still you probably want to use transactions to ensure complete rollback on error, but it can simplify locking a lot :)